# How can i open addthis popup on button click?

Tags: javascript, addthis

I have an addthis popup which now opens automatically after the page is loaded. I want this popup to open when i click on `<a class="share"><i class="fa fa-plus"></a>`. How could I get it done?

My HTML code is:

```
<ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="Facebook Share Link"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="Twitter Share Link"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="Google Share Link"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="share" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

And JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5487d4c13f47e44">
    $('.share').click();
</script>
```

Comment: @Dai, I have AdBlock, I still see the AdThis buttons?! Do you use AdBlock to prevent those buttons? You don't like to share others content ever?

Comment: @Dai OP's question is to make sharing functionality *more* convenient for users and less in their face as the default AddThis popup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [AddThis API](https://www.addthis.com/academy/addthis-core-share-follow-api/) to wire up to your own custom controls.

Another way to accomplish what you want is to hide the target AddThis `<div />` with CSS `display: none` for example, then display it (or move it in the DOM) wherever you like, such as in your own custom popup, when the user clicks the main "share" button.